# Does $\sin (y) + y = x^3 + x$ determine $y$ as a function of $x$?

Tags: calculus, functions, implicit-differentiation

I was teaching my calculus class, and we were learning implicit differentiation. I learned it quite differently when I was at school, but regardless we found that $\sin (y) + y = x^3 + x$ has the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3x^2 + 1}{\cos (y)+1}$, and is therefore vertical when $y = (2k+1)\pi$ for all integers $k$. However, this only occurs locally at a single point, and while we're unable to find a function $y = f(x)$ (or vice versa) that would allow us to find a value of $x$ for the aforementioned value of $y$, I'm inclined to believe that it's a function. My students were very curious about the idea (even though it was slightly off topic, we were tryin to find the tangent line at $(0,0)$ ) and so I presented as evidence to my guess that it would be a function that the derivative never goes negative, and is only undefined at a point. How might I prove this more rigorously.

Comment: In order for $y$ to be a function of $x$, your equation must determine the value of $y$ for a given value of $x$, say $x=a$. In other words, the equation $$\sin y+y=\text{a constant}$$ must have a unique solution (if it has one at all). The question thus boils down to asking whether the function $g(z)=\sin z+z$ (I'm changing the letter just for emphasis) is one-to-one. You can make some progress on this by thinking about its derivative and some other basic facts.

Answer (score 6):

It's equivalent to asking if $f(x)=\sin(x)+x$ is injective. The fact that $f$ is injective almost follows from the mean value theorem, although you need a bit of care since $f'(x)=\cos(x)+1$ hits zero. On any interval $[a,b]$, however, $f'(x)$ is nonnegative and continuous and attains a positive value, so $f(b)=f(a)+\int_a^bf'$ is strictly greater than $f(a)$.

---

Expanding on the first sentence: we need to make sure that, if $(x,y_1)$ and $(x,y_2)$ are solutions to $\sin(y)+y=x^3+x$, then $y_1=y_2$. Since $\sin(y_1)+y_1=\sin(y_2)+y_2$, we're really just checking that $y\mapsto \sin(y)+y$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you, very clever method, and yes very similar to the notion of injectivity. Though these students haven't really studied injectivity directly (their notion of one-to-one is pretty much limited to "the horizontal line test" at the moment, but of course the reason behind checking values of (x,y1) and (x,y2) is appropriate for this class.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an implicitly-defined function. Let's take a look at the two sides of the equation separately.

Let $u = x^3+x$. Then, $u$ is a function of $x$, and more importantly, it's a one-to-one function. This follows pretty easily from the fact that it's strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$: $u'(x) = 3x^2 + 1 > 0$.

So, for any $x$ we choose in $\mathbb{R}$, there is a unique $u$ associated with it, and for any $u$ we choose in the range (also $\mathbb{R}$), there is a unique $x$ associated with it.

The same thing holds for the left-hand side. Let $v = \sin(y) + y$. Then, $v$ is strictly increasing in $y$. We can't get there using the derivative alone: $v'(y) = \cos(y)+1 \ge 0$. We'll end up with $v' = 0$ periodically (the same vertical tangents your class found).

A strictly positive derivative is sufficient for strict monotonicity, but it's not necessary. We have a weakly increasing function from the derivative, and we also know that the intercepts of $v'$ are isolated points. Together, that still gives us that for any $y_1$ and $y_2$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $y_1 < y_2 \Rightarrow v(y_1) < v(y_2)$, i.e., $v$ is strictly monotonic in $y$. This in turn means that $v$ and $y$ have a one-to-one relationship.

Then, combining the two paragraphs above, we have $u = v$, obviously strictly monotonic, therefore also one-to-one. That lets us map a one-to-one relation between $x$ and $y$: for any specific $x$, there is exactly one $u$. For any given $u$, there is exactly one $v$. And for any specific $v$, there is exactly one $y$.

Comment: The injectivity of $u$ is irrelevant. Replacing $x^3+x$ with $x^2$, say, also determines $y$ as a function of $x$ (on all of $\mathbb{R}$). All that matters is that $u$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Sure. But for a calculus teacher who wants to provide an explanation to high school students studying this for the first time, it's just easier to see through bijections rather than surjections or injections, which are concepts most high school students have never heard of. They do know what a one-to-one function is though, that's why I took that approach.

Comment: You’re missing the point. The second and third paragraphs of your answer are totally irrelevant. It doesn’t matter whether the right side of the equation is one-to-one. (Injective and one-to-one mean the same thing.) All that matters is that (1) the right side of the equation is a function solely of $x$, and (2) the left side is one-to-one as a function of $y$.